# Unable to distinguish between admin and student session login

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am creating a php MySQL website, the problem is I have both admin and user login link available on website. Now if I login from student account and then click in the admin link the functionality of admin are also open. Meaning that the Session variable I am using to identify where the session is active or not is unable to distinguish between student and admin session.
Please help.

code:

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
#PROCEED
}
?>
```

Here, $_SESSION['uname'] is username from the database table, while admin login its from admin table and while student login its from their table. 
Since both have same code once logged in from any student or admin username I can open both the profiles. Please help me fix this.

Comment: You need to have another session variable with the type of user stored in it.  You can then test this to determine what access they have.

Comment: @NigelRen I have make different session variable now. $_SESSION['uname_a] for admin and $_SESSION['uname_s] for student but now if without logging out of account I can open both the accounts. Please help

Comment: Try leaving the username as `$_SESSION['uname']` and have another variable - something like `$_SESSION['type']`, put `admin` or `student` in it.

Answer (score 0):

bro,
you must set the second Session for auth the user
for exp

```
<?php
session_start();
//1 for admin and 2 for user
//dont use 0 because [Type Juggling][1] 
if(isset($_SESSION) && $_SESSION['UserRole'] == 1){
header('location : Admin/index.php');
}elseif(isset($_SESSION) && $_SESSION['UserRole'] == 2){
header('location : User/index.php');
}else{
header('location : Login.php?msg=Login_First');
}

?>
```

Comment: I have used if condition that if $_SESSION['std']  session is on then page will show  popup while opening admin page that please first logout student and page will redirect to student page. That is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

First you should consider all admins and students as users and save all their info in users relation or table.
Second consider a column for users roles in your users relation and call the column role.
Third you should make a possibility to set role for users in your admin panel to make theme distinguishable in login process.
Imagine you did login step and sat proper session role value for admin users based on role column value, then check users role and do what ever needed for example:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if($_SESSION['user_login'] === true) {
    if($_SESSION['user_role'] === 'admin'){
        echo 'user with admin role is login';
    }else{
        echo 'user with student role is login';
    }
}
?>
```